# MySQLi problems with fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with MySQLi when it comes to fetching a row of data from the database.

```
$select="SELECT * FROM table";
$arows = $mysqli->query($select);
while ($arow = $arows->fetch_row()) {
```

Now the problem I have is illogical, because I'm getting function fetch_row() is a non-object error. However, the same code with the procedural function works fine.

```
while ($arow= mysqli_fetch_row($arows)) {
```

I've omitted the connection details because in both examples they are the same.

Comment: Is the query failing?

Comment: Is this your real code? If it is, you need to quote the table name in back-ticks as `table` is a reserved word.

Comment: I presume you're using something to the affect of `if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {`

Comment: The names have been changed to protect the innocent, and I have used an if statement as well as || die; Neither throw errors from the query. Now the procedural call shouldn't work (since its using objects) but it works better than the objects.

Comment: The query succeeds and mysqli_fetch_row returns correctly, which I feel shouldn't work (because its mixing procedural and object oriented code) but it works and the object oriented code doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use exactly the same connection code for the procedural and object interfaces.

To connect with the object interface you need to run the object constructor like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

It's possible your $mysqli->query() call kicked back a false if $mysqli wasn't constructed correctly. That would cause your problem.

Many people put

```
 || die ('message');
```

after their dbms calls to catch this sort of thing.

Comment: I actually use the object interface to connect to the database and I tried the die but it still failed at the fetch_row. It drove me bonkers until I discovered the procedural and swapped only that line of code and it worked!?!